# Default value format of a stored procedure parameter(of datatype : money)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, format, money, locales

With my query:

```
SELECT (CAST(0.00 AS MONEY))
```

I am expecting a result : 0.00

But it shows me the result: 0,00(with comma)

I checked this query ,when i found that,the `CREATE PROCEDURE` script displays the default value as 
[money] = 0,0000, for one of the input parameters of a procedure.

How can i make the CREATE PROCEDURE display it with '.' instead of ','?

Comment: What is the currency setting on the server machine itself? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Display formatting is controlled by the application, not the database server. Although you could format the data as desired in T-SQL and return a string instead, I recommend doing so in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Decimal symbol in the Regional settings and changed it from ',' to '.'

Now,the CREATE PROCEDURE display it with '.' instead of ','

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: That works for that one client machine, great! Now are you going to go change the regional settings of all the other users who access this database?

Comment: This database is accessed only by limited number of client machines OR it is accessed by only limited number of developers.The formatting became an issue when one of the third party comparison tool which we are using was picking up this regional setting of local machine and showed it as a difference with the source control version of the procedure.

Comment: That still doesn’t make this a good solution (for you *or* for others to learn from), IMHO.

Comment: I agree.I would say this is a workaround for now until the Third party tool support team, help us to overcome this.